# Cordova InAppBrowser plugin broken for OSX platform

Tags: macos, cordova

When compiling a cordova macos app with the InAppBrowser plugin installed under Mojave 10.14.2 and Xcode 10.1 I get the following error message:

> ERROR: Plugin 'InAppBrowser' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml

I've checked the config.xml, and it contains the correct entry:

> ```
> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^3.0.0" />
> ```

I've looked in /plugins and the plugin and its xml file are there.

I've removed and added the plugin and the platform.

Taking a cue [from this old (and marked fixed) bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13424), I manually inserted the following into the config.xml file in Xcode:

```
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="osx-package" value="CDVDevice" />
</feature>
```

That changes the error message to this:

> ERROR: Method 'open:' not defined in Plugin 'InAppBrowser'

Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<platform name="osx">  
    ... 
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
        <param name="osx-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
    </feature>
    ...
</platform>
```

This works for me.